# For each div insert.before image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of articles generated on a page. I have to insert the image above the article on the right, inside the text.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <div class="image  cf-img-right-small ">
            <div  class="cmp-image">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="images"  alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
            the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="cont">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <div class="image  cf-img-right-small ">
            <div  class="cmp-image">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="image"  alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
            the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.cont').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    count = $('.cont', this).children().length;
    console.log(count)
    if ((count < 2) && ( $( ".cf-img-right-small" ).length )) {

        $( ".image:first-child" ).insertBefore($( ".cont p" ) );   
    
    } 
});
</script>
```

My issue is when i have 2 articles ore more ,the one with image will put the image and all the articles.

Comment: I don't see what exactly you are trying to do. Could you please specify your issue a bit? Maybe with an image describing what you want to do?

did you try console.log($(".image:first-child")) ?

Comment: If i have helped fixing your issue then please accept it as correct answer or else let me know have any question.

Comment: **I have to insert the image above the article on the right, inside the text.** Here what do you mean by **inside the text.** ?

Comment: Hey Ankur, it doesn't work, i don't no why, but it doesn't enter the this if " ($(this).find(".cf-img-right-small" ).length ) {"

Comment: `$(this).find(".cf-img-right-small" ).length` This line checks for element with class `cf-img-right-small`. If you changed that class in your code then only it will not work. Otherwise it will work. So the thing is if you have changed code then update it here.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code i have fixed issue with multiple articles. You were missing current .cont element reference while getting image and inserting before p.

Also `$( ".image:first-child" )` here class was wrong. Right class was `.images`.

```js
$('.cont').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.find(".cf-img-right-small").length) {
    $this.find(".images:first-child").insertBefore($this.find("p"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <div class="image  cf-img-right-small ">
      <div class="cmp-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="images" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <div class="image  cf-img-right-small ">
      <div class="cmp-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?121" class="images" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```